# Saving a new form field in database in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1, symfony-2.1, orangehrm

I started symfony today. I have to add a new field in a form and save that in a table (orange hrm customization ). 
I created a new form field **comment**. I altered the target table also. When I submit the form comment is not saving. I think I have to do some configuration in symfony to save **comment** in database. please help me to solve the issue

**EDIT: My code is**

```
    public function execute($request) { 

        $this->form = $this->getForm();

        print "<pre>";
    print_r($this->form->getValues());
    print "</pre>";

    //Output shows [comment] => dddd

    $leaveEntitlement = $this->getLeaveEntitlement($this->form->getValues());

    print "<pre>";
    print_r($leaveEntitlement);
    print "</pre>";



    LeaveEntitlement Object
    (
    [_node:protected] => 
    [_id:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
    )

    [_data:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [emp_number] => 3
        [no_of_days] => 384
        [days_used] => 0.0000
        [leave_type_id] => 2
        [from_date] => 2014-01-01 00:00:00
        [to_date] => 2014-01-31 00:00:00

        [credited_date] => 2014-01-30 00:00:00
        [note] => 
        [entitlement_type] => 1
        [deleted] => 0
        [created_by_id] => 1
        [created_by_name] => Admin
    )

    [_values:protected] => Array
    (
    )


    // It is not showing [comment] => dddd
}
```

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. You can do so by editing your own question, and adding it there, in the body of the question. It will help us helping you. And please, tell us which version of symfony you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This magic must happen in your Controller and you have to use two things:

You've got to call `$form->handleRequest($request)`

You also need to persist your entity with `$em->persist($entity)->flush()`

Here is an example based on your code. This is the part of the controller when you handle your form:

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function executeAction($request)
    {
        $entity = new Comment;
        $form = $this->createForm(new CommentType(), $entity);

            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid())
            {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); // this is where it begins
                $em->persist($entity); // it goes on
                $em->flush(); // done!

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('your_next_url'));
            }

            return $this->render('YourBundle:YourDirectory:template.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ));
    }
}
```